# Regext to match word in URL

Tags: regex

URL = https://www.etsy.com/listing/257072194/shopkins-invitation-shopkins-invite

I need a pattern that return the url that containing word "invitation"

Comment: In which language?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

This will match an URL from website www.etsy.com containing the word "invitation":

```
^(http|https)://www.etsy.com/.*invitation
```